# How to set the same crop settings for all documents being scanned?

Tags: windows-7, scanner, scanning, crop

I'm scanning a lot of images using  **Windows Fax & Scan**. I reduced the DPI to speed up the process. All photos are the same size, so I was wondering if I can crop them all at once.

Right now, I have to:

1. Preview
2. Crop
3. Scan

Is there an software which can crop all my images using the same settings?

Comment: Yeah, the Windows XP scanner interface was nicer for having this.